# Forms data not updating

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one user form in which users login & can view all there information which is already stored in database. So onPageLoad I have select query. Now If user wants to update any record from textfield they can edit but here the information I modify is not making update in database. here is my code.

I tried to breakpoint on my update query & under that I do not see the updated information which I fill. It takes the existing one only.

OnPageLoad

```
Private Sub list_business_hospital_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Try
                Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM  hospitals WHERE username='" + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value) + "';"
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim lblservice As New Label
                For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
                    If chk.Selected = True Then
                        lblservice.Text = String.Concat(lblservice.Text + ",", chk.Value)

                    End If
                Next

                da.Fill(dt)
                con.Close()
                TextId.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hospitalID").ToString
                businessName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString
                welcome.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString
                subCat.Text = dt.Rows(0)("subcategory").ToString
                contactPerson.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactPerson").ToString
                websiteName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("websiteName").ToString
                emailName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("email").ToString
                phone1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("phone1").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Update Button

```
Private Sub updateInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateInfo.Click
        Try
            Dim con As New MySqlConnection
            Dim query As New MySqlCommand
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            query.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            query.CommandText = "UPDATE hospitals SET name = '" + businessName.Text + "', contactPerson = '" + contactPerson.Text + "', websiteName = '" + websiteName.Text + "', email = '" + emailName.Text + "', phone1 = '" + phone1.Text + "' WHERE hospitalID = '" & TextId.Text + "'"
            query.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Information updated successfully.');</script>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update query you have used hospitalID = '" & TextId.Text + "' which is wrong. You have inseeted & +

Make it like this

```
query.CommandText = "UPDATE hospitals SET name = '" + businessName.Text + "', contactPerson = '" + contactPerson.Text + "', websiteName = '" + websiteName.Text + "', email = '" + emailName.Text + "', phone1 = '" + phone1.Text + "' WHERE hospitalID = '" + TextId.Text + "'"
```

Answer (score -1):

In select you used username to find record and in update you used hospitalID. It should work, but if its not working, can you please try to update record by username?

Comment: It should be a comment.